# Interpretation of Elastic net having too low or high value of alpha

Tags: model-selection, lasso, ridge-regression, elastic-net

Often I found the situation that the elastic model what I fitted has optimal alpha value at 0 or 1. Or not only that situation, but also there some alphas go near to 0 or 1.(ex. 0.1 or 0.9)
My Question is : Is there anything to mean that the alphas tends to go to 0 or 1?

(Added for more clarification)
If in my dataset the ratio of the number of predictors highly correlated with dependent variable is high, the Elastic net model remains more predictors. Then the model is more appropriate to ridge model than lasso.

Does my guess make sense logically?

Comment: You've tagged this question with [tag:lasso] and [tag:ridge-regression], so I suspect you already know the connection between elastic net, lasso and ridge regression and how the values of $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=0$  are related to lasso and ridge. So can you clarify what you mean by "interpretation" beyond the lasso/ridge connection?

Comment: Yes. I know about the relations. Beyond the lasso/ridge connections, What I wonder is that a tendency that an fitted elastic model go to ridge model(alpha=0) or lasso model (alpha=1) can be changed by constructions of predictors.

Comment: In my think, a tendency to go to ridge remains all variables and to go to lasso remains most needed variables can be attributed to how highly correlated predictors to dependent variable

Comment: Ok, but that's just a description of lasso and ridge.

Comment: If in my dataset the ratio of the number of predictors highly correlated with dependent variable is high, the Elastic net model remains more predictors. Then the model is more appropriate to ridge model than lasso

Comment: Does my guess make sense logically?

Comment: I understand better what you're asking about. Can you [edit] this description into your question?

Comment: Ok. I did it. maybe it need more clarification....